# Error while processing .vimrc in vagrant when I run `git commit -v`

Tags: plugin-vundle

I am working on a CentOs machine. **Vim works fine**. But when I `git commit -v` It seems that something is wrong:

```
[vagrant@localhost dotfiles]$ git add .
[vagrant@localhost dotfiles]$ git commit -v
Error detected while processing /home/vagrant/.vimrc:
line    6:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'            " vim bundle manager
line    7:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'               " finder ...
line    8:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'fugitive.vim'                 " git integration
line    9:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils' " add your local vimrc
line   10:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
line   11:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'          " add snippets to your vim
line   12:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'          " tree of files and folders
line   13:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'tommcdo/vim-lion'             " align equals
line   14:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'vim-php/vim-composer'
line   29:
E518: Unknown option: foldlevel=1
line   30:
E518: Unknown option: foldlevelstart=42
line   31:
E518: Unknown option: foldmethod=indent
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: It seems like `Vundle` didn't get installed properly, leading to ever `Vundle` command failing. How did you install `Vundle`, and what does your `.vimrc` contain?

Comment: What is the value of `$EDITOR`? Is it `vim` or `vi`?

Comment: `$ echo $EDITOR` return an empty line?!?!?!

Comment: `git config --global core.editor vim` works for me

Comment: It looks like you're running `vim` as `vi`, which means it disables a bunch of features. Try `export EDITOR=vim` and run `git commit` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that Vundle isn't installed on your vagrant VM.

You should connect to your VM, issue the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

And issue `:PluginInstall` in vim on your VM.

I think it is possible to use puppet to pre-configure your vagrant installation to include Vundle but I never tried it; I always do it manually.

Also you might be interested in a scrip like [this one](https://gist.github.com/fideloper/7552992) to get inspiration on how to automatically add Vundle to a fresh install *(as said in the article linked on top of the page the script works only with an empty `.vimrc`. I give you this link only as an inspiration)*.

Comment: But Vundle is installed :-/. Vim works, I am working with Vim!! And I work inside vagrant machine.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't understand that, my bad. Peter's comment on your question might be a better approach then.

Comment: Why is this marked as the right answer, in regard to the above comments? This is confusing for visitors.